# Bind Image Source in WPF to a Url

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, winrt-xaml

I having been browsing around different posts trying to figure out what is wrong with my issue. Basically I have a Image tag on my user control, and the Source I would like to bind to a url. However this does not work. I have tried using a ValueConverter that returns `BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value));`
but this does not work. The only thing I have been able to get is that you cannot bind to a url and that you have to download the image you want to bind. I do not want to download all images I seacrch. Is there a work around to achieving this task with out having to download the image locally. I thought the ValueConverter method would have been the best by return a BitmapImage. Please help?

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private string _posterUrl;
        public string PosterUrl
        {
            get
            {
                //Get Image Url, this is an example and will be retrieved from somewhere else.
                _posterUrl = "http://www.eurobuzz.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/logo.jpg";
                return _posterUrl;    
            }
            set 
            { 
                _posterUrl = value;
                NofityPropertyChanged(p => p.PosterUrl);
            }
        }
}
```

This is my ValueConverter:

```
public class BitmapImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is string)
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string)value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        if(value is Uri)
            return new BitmapImage((Uri)value);

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

This is my XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding PosterUrl, Converter={StaticResource bitmapImageConverter}}" Width="100" Height="100" />
```

So this is binding to the PosterUrl property that contains the imageurl and this is converted to a bitmapimage. Any ideas?

Comment: Please find my code above

Comment: That should all work perfectly. Perhaps the request for that URL doesn't pass your web proxy. Can you retrieve the image in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Fortunately, I have no proxy and it does pop up in IE

Comment: Should even work without the converter, a string is automatically convertered to BitmapSource by built-in TypeConverter. Could you try (just for a test) something like `var data = (new WebClient()).DownloadData("<your url>");`? Should give you a byte array containing the image buffer, just to see if download works.

Comment: This works. The other thing I have not mentioned is that this is a Windows 8 application. Could it be that in WinRT this behavior is different. Please advise?

Comment: its a Windows Store App.

Comment: Well, then it's not WPF. You should remove the `wpf` and `silverlight` tags, and add `winrt`. If the problem is still unsolved, I'll continue to investigate tonight when i have access to a Win8 system.

Comment: Binding `Image.Source` to an URL string works well without converter in a Windows Store App. Since you didn't set any `Source` or `RelativeSource` in your binding, did you perhaps just forget to set an appropriate [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=win.10).aspx)? Something like `DataContext = new MyViewModel()` in the MainPage constructor.

Comment: I set the following:<Page.DataContext>
        <vm:MediaBrowserSearchViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext> for the view model. everything else binds correctly. May I send you me code?

Comment: Looks ok. You may simply edit your question if there is more to post.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<Image Helpers:ImageAsyncHelper.SourceUri="{Binding Url, IsAsync=True}" x:Name="img" />
```

Where

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class ImageAsyncHelper : DependencyObject {
    public static Uri GetSourceUri(DependencyObject obj){
        return (Uri)obj.GetValue(SourceUriProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSourceUri(DependencyObject obj, Uri value){
        obj.SetValue(SourceUriProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceUriProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SourceUri",
            typeof(Uri),
            typeof(ImageAsyncHelper),
            new PropertyMetadata { PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, e) =>
                ((Image)obj).SetBinding(
                    Image.SourceProperty,
                    new Binding("VerifiedUri"){
                        Source = new ImageAsyncHelper{
                            _givenUri = (Uri)e.NewValue
                        },
                        IsAsync = true
                    }
                )
            }
        );

    private Uri _givenUri;
    public Uri VerifiedUri {
        get {
            try {
                System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(_givenUri.DnsSafeHost);
                return _givenUri;
            }
            catch (Exception) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
public Uri Url {
    get {
        return new Uri(SomeString, UriKind.Absolute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this ?

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding}" />

    <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="http://www.eurobuzz.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/logo.jpg"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind :

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        this.DataContext = "http://www.eurobuzz.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/logo.jpg";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```